# Regular expression to replace a value in query parameter in java

Tags: java, sql, regex, oracle11g

I am writing one application to search for specific fields in the form and display the corresponding query to the user (user can save the executed query and load the query later). I am using an API to generate the query based on the selected fields. The API returns the generated query in following format.

***Generated query***:

```
SELECT T0."id" AS "COL0" 
FROM   student_table T0 
WHERE  ( ( ( T0."student_name" = ? ) 
           AND ( T0."grade" = ? ) ) 
         AND ( T0."student_no" LIKE ? ) )
```

***Expected query***:

```
SELECT T0."id" AS "COL0" 
FROM   student_table T0 
WHERE  ( ( ( T0."student_name" = 'John' ) 
           AND ( T0."grade" = 'A' ) ) 
         AND ( T0."student_no" LIKE '12%' ) )
```

Now I have to build proper query from above query. Since I have the field values in the from, I want to replace the "?" with corresponding values.

**Is it possible to replace the '?' with corresponding field values using java string replaceAll method ? can we use the concept of back references to replace the question marks with corresponding values ? If not possible with regex please suggest a better approach to solve the problem.**

I think prepared statement wont help much since I need to automate this process for hundreds of fields which are unordered and it is a very costly operation also. (correct me If I am wrong)

I am actually using my company specific platform API, I am adding criteria's and query columns to the query definition and it returns the executed query in the above mentioned format. User should be able to save the Expected query, I should display both the query and result of query in UI.

Comment: take a look at preparedStatement. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: wat api u r using and how

Comment: show the query building code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to execute query in following way

```
  String insertTableSQL = "SELECT T0.\"ID\" AS \"COL0\" FROM STUDENT_TABLE T0 WHERE ( ( ( T0.\"STUDENT_NAME\" =  ?  ) AND ( T0.\"GRADE\" =  ?  ) ) AND ( T0.\"STUDENT_NO\" LIKE  ?  ) )";               
             PreparedStatement preparedStatement = dbConnection.prepareStatement(insertTableSQL);

            preparedStatement.setString(1, "John");
            preparedStatement.setString(2, "A");
            preparedStatement.setString(3, "12%");
            preparedStatement.execute();
```

Comment: As OP said he already built the query. He just want to know how to execute this query. So I have provided it :)

Comment: I think he need to build the query with values. So if we see the build code, we can suggest how to set the values.

Comment: The OP says,"
I am writing one application to search for specific fields in the form. I am using an API to generate the query based on the selected fields. The api returns the generated query in following format."
So I don't think so he want to create query.
What he wants to replace ? with proper value

Answer (score 1):

You can use PreparedStatement to execute such queries that contains ?

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;
ResultSet rs = null;

String sQuery = "SELECT T0."ID" AS "COL0" FROM STUDENT_TABLE T0 WHERE ( ( ( T0."STUDENT_NAME" = ? ) AND ( T0."GRADE" = ? ) ) AND ( T0."STUDENT_NO" LIKE ? ) )";

ps = objConnection.prepareStatement(sQuery);
ps.setString(1, valueOf_T0."STUDENT_NAME");
ps.setString(2, valueOf_T0."GRADE");
ps.setString(3, valueOf_T0."STUDENT_NO");
rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

As you have data values and you know the type of database fields, so that you can set values in setter methods according to your data type like `setInt(), setDouble()`,etc.

Read more about : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html

Thanks